# In R: list of dataframes, automatically extract all dfs separately

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a list, where each element is a dataframe, is there some option with which I could automatically extract all the dataframes with automatically generated names?

for example: (I first have to artifically create a list here)

```
d1 <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 2, 3),
             y1 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(x2 = c(4, 5, 6),
             y2 = c(7, 8, 9))

mylist <- list()
mylist[[1]] <- d1
mylist[[2]] <- d2
```

is there some loop I could write that would extract all the elements of the list together as separate dataframe and save them in the environment?

I thought about something like

```
names <- paste0("mydata", 1:length(mylist))  #names of the dataframes
for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
names[i] <- data.frame() #initialization
names[i] <- mylist[[i]]
}
```

and then  all dataframes should generated into the environment, but unfortunately this does not work, the problem is in the initialization step. it can not create empty dataframes with the names[i]. Would be thankful if someone could tell me how to redo this

Comment: Use `list2env(setNames(mylist, names), .GlobalEnv)` and then check the `ls()`

Comment: @akrun, thank you I did this, now I see that the separate elements of the vector are also loaded into the environment, (mydata1, mydata2), but when I execute the for-loop I still get the same error: Error in names[i] <- data.frame() : replacement has length zero

Comment: In the for loop, you need `assign(names[i], mylist[[i]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects may be created in the global env with `list2env` on a named `list` - `setNames` sets the names of the list (it is a bad practise to create multiple objects in the global env i.e. instead keep it in the `list` itself)

```
list2env(setNames(mylist, names), .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Regarding the OP's code, to create objects in `for` loop, use `assign` and not `names<-`

```
for (i in seq_along(mylist))
    {
     assign(names[i], mylist[[i]])
    }
```